# Get birthday with a query

Tags: mysql

I have problems to get age of certain dates.

```
SELECT birthday, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(birthday)), '%Y')+0 AS age FROM users;
```

The result is:

```
| 27-07-1955 | NULL |
```

What's wrong in this select?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this query, it better:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(t.birthday, '%d-%m-%Y'))/365 AS ageInYears
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

Comment: Nope, that gives a lot of incoorect answers: Born on 31 dec, andthe next day you're already 1 year old this way.

Comment: O, i changed it ;)

Comment: Doesn't account for leap years, also goves wrong results.

Comment: right! I add the parameter ROUND too

Comment: Leap years are about more than rounding. You will get wrong results.

Comment: I change the table to a data type. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, CURDATE()) AS age FROM users;
```

Comment: no. all results are as NULL

Comment: Then probably birthday is all NULL, or you have a wrong data type. It works perfectly fine on a normal datefield that is not null. I tested.

Comment: I guess from your original posting you use a string. Which is not the right way to store dates, we have the DATE type for that. In that case you should use `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, str_to_date(birthday, '%d-%m-%Y'), CURDATE()) AS age FROM users;`

But I highly recommend you use the right datatype. Also, the answer you accepted als a correct answer will give wrong answers. For people over 50 sometimes really wrong.